# Reading from inner JSON Object JAVA

Tags: java, json

I think, I have the understanding of JSON down, but I am having a slight issue with reading inner objects, for example `Cover` in this situation.

```
    {
       "id": "19292868552",
       "about": "Build, grow, and monetize your app with Facebook.\nhttps://developers.facebook.com/",
       "can_post": false,
       "category": "Product/service",
       "checkins": 1,
       "company_overview": "Visit https://developers.facebook.com for more information on how to build, grow, and monetize your app.\n\nIf you have questions about using Facebook or need help with general inquiries, visit https://www.facebook.com/facebook or our Help Center at http://www.facebook.com/help.\n\nIf you need to report bugs, appeal apps, or ask detailed technical questions, visit the following:\nAppeal Apps: https://developers.facebook.com/appeal\nReport Bugs: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs\nTechnical Questions: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/",
       "cover": {
          "cover_id": "10152004458663553",
          "offset_x": 0,
          "offset_y": 0,
          "source": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xap1/v/t1.0-9/s720x720/1466030_10152004458663553_1984809612_n.jpg?oh=97b895edc21d21c0f40a67a6de6077bd&oe=54BBD66C&__gda__=1422540117_30f73303c987294f8ffccd193d190941"
       },
       "has_added_app": false,
       "is_community_page": false,
       "is_published": true,
       "likes": 3262128,
       "link": "https://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers",
       "name": "Facebook Developers",
       "parking": {
          "lot": 0,
          "street": 0,
          "valet": 0
       },
       "talking_about_count": 10066,
       "username": "FacebookDevelopers",
       "website": "http://developers.facebook.com",
       "were_here_count": 0
    }
```

I was hoping to have this read from the JSON, it all works until I hit the Cover part. I have not tried to access the `parking` object yet, but I assume the issue will be the same.

```
    public FacebookCover createFacebookCoverObject (String json) throws 
        JSONException {

    FacebookCover facebookCover = new FacebookCover();


    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);



    facebookCover.setAbout(obj.getString("about"));
    facebookCover.setCategory(obj.getString("category"));
    facebookCover.setCompanyOverview(obj.getString("company_overview"));
    facebookCover.setId(obj.getString("id"));
    facebookCover.setIsPublished(obj.getBoolean("is_published"));
    facebookCover.setLikes(obj.getInt("likes"));
    facebookCover.setLink(obj.getString("link"));
    facebookCover.setName(obj.getString("name"));
    facebookCover.setTalkingAboutCount(obj.getInt("talking_about_count"));
    facebookCover.setUserName(obj.getString("username"));
    facebookCover.setWebsite(obj.getString("website"));
    facebookCover.setWereHereCount(obj.getInt("were_here_count"));

    Cover theCover = new Cover();

    JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject();

    theCover.setCoverId((obj2.getString("cover_id")));
    theCover.setOffSetX(obj2.getInt("offset_x"));
    theCover.setOffSetY(obj2.getInt("offset_y"));
    theCover.setSource(obj2.getString("source"));

    return facebookCover;

}
```

Here is also my test method.

```
public void testCreateFavebookCoverObject() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("createFavebookCoverObject");
    String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/19292868552/";
    InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    String s = null;

    s = rd.readLine();
    System.out.println(s);
    FacebookCover instance = new FacebookCover();
    FacebookCover result = instance.createFacebookCoverObject(s);
}
```

Comment: Why would `JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject();` contain anything?

Comment: Sorry I meant to change it...that was my issue. Was being fairly dumb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should do the trick :

```
JSONObject obj2 = obj.getJSONObject("cover");
```

Comment: Yes that should do it.

Comment: Thanks guys, the solved it...I should have know that. However now when I pass the JSON string, I am getting the error message `must begin with '{' at character 1.` I am starting to heavily dislike JSON. I added my testFacebookCover to the block above.